# Find all elements with an 'id' attribute on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tree-traversal

Simple.  I want to traverse the DOM and find all elements that have an id attribute.  Can someone help me with a js and/or jquery script

Comment: Didn't see that duplicate when creating this question.  Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can query all the elements with an `id` attribute by using the following jQuery selector:

```
$("[id]")
```

You can also just use plain JavaScript using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id]")
```

If you want to find *non-empty* `id` attributes, use this selector instead:

```
'[id]:not([id]="")'
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer for completeness of answer.

Comment: think that should be... `'[id]:not([id=""])'`

Comment: Hello just a side question - as [id] is a very special attribute - is there maybe a more direct and more efficient way to access the list of all elements having an id?

Answer (score 3):

Simple attribute selector

```
$('[id]');
```

Reference : [Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)